# Как передать объекту ссылку

Tags: c++

Возможно глупый вопрос, не судите строго. В общем, у меня есть объект на него нужно передать ссылку этого-же типа. Думаю код лучше вам объяснит ситуацию:

```
class ObjA{

};
class ObjB{
    ObjA *a;
public:
    ObjB(const ObjA& _a){
        a = _a;
    }
};
```

При таком коде вылетает такая ошибка: "cannot convert ‘const ObjA’ to ‘ObjA*’ in assignment". Я как понимаю ошибка в том что невозможно сконвертировать ссылочный тип к обычному. P.S Ещё раз извиняюсь за мои возможные ошибки в тексте, из-за непонимания работы С++. Буду рад почитать в комментариях поправки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну смотрите: у вас в объекте хранится УКАЗАТЕЛЬ на `ObjA`, в то же время в конструктор вы передаете ССЫЛКУ на `ObjA`. У вас несовпадение типов, так как нельзя конвертить ссылку к указателю. Сдесь у вас два варианта:

1) взять адрес `OjbA` и присвоить его указателю. Так как адрес ссылки == адресу переменной, то это не проблема, но у вас указатель на неконстантный объект `ObjA`, а в конструктор вы передаете константную ссылку, так что либо вы снимаете константность с ссылки, либо добавляете ее к указателю

2) Хранить в `ObjB` ссылку, а не указатель. Да, так можно (ссылка это фактически указатель, который не нужно разыменовывать и который не может быть `nullptr`(на самом деле может быть, но это другая история)), так что вы можете хранить ссылку в объекте при условии, что она будет инициализирована в конструкторе. По поводу константности - смотрите пункт 1.

В конечном итоге у вас должно получиться что-то вроде:

```cpp
class ObjA{

};
class ObjB{
    const ObjA *a;
public:
    ObjB(const ObjA& _a){
        a = &_a;
    }
};
```

или

```cpp
class ObjA{

};
class ObjB{
    const ObjA &a;
public:
    ObjB(const ObjA& _a){
        a = _a;
    }
};
```

PS в конечном итоге вариант, который стоит выбрать, зависит от изменяемости переменной, ссылающейся на `ObjA` - если в `ObjB` она может быть изменена (имеется ввиду не объект по указателю, а сам указатель), то стоит выбрать вариани с указателем, иначе можно выбрать ссылку.

Comment: Во втором варианте ссылку нужно инициализировать в списке инициализации.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, забыли взятие адреса: `a = &_a;`

Во-вторых, нужно либо убрать `const` с `const ObjA& _a`, либо добавить его к `ObjA *a;`.